# install Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server on Windows 8

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Does Windows 8 supports `sql server driver` for php.
I found that system Requirements for `sql Driver` does not contain Windows 8.
I installed and configured sql driver for php on wamp server, but `sqlsrv` doesn't show in `phpinfo()`.

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine for me on windows 8, if you don't activate the good extension in php.ini, by default (int XAMP) the slqsrv extension is selected  `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll`, in my case, I am using PHP 5.4 and have configured the following extension:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

See Readme file provided with the installation drivers to see which extension to activate in your case.

Restart the server and it's done.

Comment: it is normal to lose reputation points, if the grammar of a response is modified